# How can I add a definition with several words to the spell checker?

Tags: spell-checking

I'm writing a paper on logic where I mention the rule *modus ponens* often.

Neither *modus* nor *ponens* are words in English, and the ideal spell checker should mark them as incorrect. However, *modus ponens* is a correct word, and should be marked correctly.

Is it possible to do something like this with the Vim spellchecker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In normal mode, `zg` adds the word under cursor as a **g**ood word to `'spellfile'`. In visual mode, the selected text is added. So selecting the word *modus ponens* and pressing `zg` will work.

Also, *modus* is recognized as a good word in `Vim`. Use `zw` to mark it as **w**rong.

You may need to put this line of code in your `.vimrc` to specify the path to `'spellfile'`:

```
set spellfile=$HOME/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
```

Comment: > Also, modus is recognized as a good word in Vim.

Not in Spanish Vim!

Thanks for the answer. It seems to work.